# 2 simple doubts about graph theory problems

Tags: graph-theory

The first one:

In this exercise I am asked to compute the number of 4-regular graphs of order 7.

I had an idea but I don't really know if it is the correct way of proceeding:

In a graph of order 7, the maximum degree is 6. Then, to find all 4-regular graphs, we can find all 2-regular graphs and take complementaries. However -I don't know if this is correct- in a 2-regular graph is a cycle, and all cycles of order 7 are isomorphic and thereby, there is only 1 4-regular graph of order 7.

The second one:

In this one, I am quite lost. I would like some ideas on how to start the proof.

Let G be a self-complementary graph whose order is congruent with 1 modulo 4, i.e. n = 4k + 1. I am asked to prove that there is an odd number of vertices of degree (n-1)/2, and of course, at least 1.

Thanks a lot! Any help is welcome :)

Comment: About your first question: "... all cycles of order $7$ are isomorphic.." is not correct. It is true that a $2$-regular graph is a UNION of cycles, that is, on $7$ vertices you will have two non-isomorphic $2$-regular graphs: (1) a $7$-cycle, (2) a $3$-cycle and a $4$ cycle.

Comment: Thanks, but in the case there is only 1 connected component, a 2 regular graph should only ONE cycle right? I mean, it might be a union of cycles in the case there are multiple connected components, right?

Comment: any $4$-regular graph on $7$ vertices must be connected (easy to see this). What I wrote is about $2$-regular graphs on $7$ vertices. You are trying to classify $4$-regular graphs, and your idea is to use the complement (good idea!), I was just trying to give you a hint that you did not consider all $2$-regular options properly, that is, the complement can be disconnected! still the $4$-regular complement to a union of a $3$-cycle and a $4$-cycle will be connected.

Comment: Okay, I see your point now very clearly! Thanks for your help :)